# XNA: What is Viewport?

Tags: c#, xna, viewport

In terms of 2D I don't understand what a viewport is and what it is used for.
I am trying to build a side-scroller and believe I need the viewport for the map scrolling part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider a Tv displaying a scene, the viewport is simply the area of the scene that is captured by the camera.

Another way of thinking about it is the way some cameraman hold up their thumbs and index fingers to 'frame' a scene, or hold up a hollow picture frame, the light that passes through that frame is the viewport.

For a visual example, consider this gif, the green rectangle is the viewport:
[image]

Comment: So say i draw things that extend off the right side of the screen. If I were to move the  default viewport to the right would i be able to see the things off the screen?
In the picture above if there were objects outside of the green rectangle, could I move the green rectangle to show those objects? (move the viewport)

Comment: Yes that's right, although I think you'd only actually move the camera, the viewport only needs to change if your altering the view frustrum, to gain a wider field of view. The frustum is the black pyramid in the picture.

Comment: Ok so I think i basically understand what a viewport is but what I don't get is how it fits into scrolling tiles across the screen. What's the point of using a viewport?

Comment: That is a good question, there are numerous reasons but I can list 2 for now, one is that it sets a focal length, if the viewport is too close or too far away, your scene will be distorted, the other is asLunin said, the viewport is a known 2d plane that can be used for positioning sprites, HUD elements, crosshairs and so on.

Comment: Before directX and 3d hardware, the viewport was also important as the plane where you turn a 3d position into a 2d pixel.

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is how the viewport fits in with drawing the tiles only shown on the screen. (The map is bigger than the screen)

Comment: Ahh oh, i'm trying to thing of a good way to put it ... the Viewport is like your eye, you can only see so much to your left and right, or above or below you when you look straigh ahead, yes ? Thats because your eye is constrained by the iris only letting in a certain amount of light, the Viewport is the computers logical representation of that - it only shows the pixels that your camera is looking at. in the same way that if the focal point of your eye is wrong and you're short or long sighted, the viewport ensures that the 3D image is focussed and not distorted.

Comment: Right, I think I get that but in side scrollers,  viewports are used as cameras to show only the tiles on the screen that are visible to the user.
+++|+++++++++++|+++
Say for example the lines represent the viewport and the plus's are tiles. Am I supposed to move the viewports position to show the other tiles?

Comment: yes, but your not actually moving the viewport, i think we're mixing terms here, assuming your 3d world is aligned properly, the way  to move the 'viewport' so it looks like the tiles are scrolling is to translate the cameras position along its x axis. this movement automatically moves the viewport.

Comment: So in reality am I drawing out the entire world and just moving the camera to the right position? If so, isn't this ineffecient?

Comment: It seems so at first but the alternative is to move everything in the world per frame, moving the camera is much better!

Comment: So how would I go about drawing only the tiles that appear on the screen? Would I use map culling? If so, how does map culling fit in with the camera?

Comment: That's the beauty of the viewport, it automatically works out what you can see.

Comment: I found this thread that might be of use:  http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/38320/223154.aspx

Comment: Hmm... I'm a bit confused. Say I have a 2d array holding the map data. In the draw method I set the viewport. In the Draw method I also iterate over the 2d array and draw the entire map using the spritebatch. How does the viewport prevent the parts of the map that the user can't see from being drawn? I mean I coded the draw method to iterate and draw the entire map (including what the user can't see).

Comment: Is this your own draw method or an xna method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by my own or an xna method...
I mean it gets called in the game loop and it takes in a spriteBatch and gameTime as parameters...
Does it really matter?

Comment: If your using Game.Draw the it should honour the parameters of the viewport, you have to set up the entire world so that the Draw code can works out what part of the world to display and then display it.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial, see how he sets up a scene and four viewports and doesn't worry about what can be seen?  http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/viewports-split-screen

Comment: Would it work if I pass the graphics object from the game to the class where the map is being drawn?
Also I still don't quite understand what the viewport does... In my mind im still drawing the entire map to the screen...

Comment: This is what is see going on in my mind. I draw the entirety of the map to the screen and the viewport moves to the location i need it to. So everytime I call draw the entire map is being drawn, not just the portion of the map the user can see. Is this correct?

Comment: You're not far off, but the difference is, your not drawing the entire map to the screen, your describing the entire map to XNA, which then uses the view port to display a portion of the map on screen.

Comment: Ah i see! so I don't need to calculate which tiles are going to be seen on the screen - the viewport "chooses" the tiles that are going to be displayed and displays them right? So if I were to actually calculate which tiles to be drawn instead of using a camera there wouldn't be too much of a performance difference right?

Comment: Yes. Doing it yourself might actually be worse, Some very clever people have spent a lot of time working out algorithms to determine whats visible and what's not, and to not render; In my experience, it's probably better to leave it to the camera. At first at least, Premature optimisation is a bad thing in development.

Comment: Hi guys, please edit in the pertinent details into the question and/or answer and refrain from using the comment system for a prolonged chat. The comment system is meant to provide feedback to the question/answer you're commenting on, not to comment on the comment to the comment on the comment to the comment on the comment to the comment on the ... etc. There's also the chat-rooms you should've been hinted about already at this point where you can chat all you want.

Comment: Thanks so much Russ, you really took the time to help me out! I had this problem for a while and could never quite figure it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The Viewport contains information about the actual current window displaying the game.  If you are working in 2D, the main ones you'll be dealing with will be the Width, Height, AspectRatio (saves calculating it yourself), and if you're planning to deploy to 360, the TitleSafeArea (The rectangle safe to draw to on all TV's, older TV's will clip 5-10% of some of the edges)

You probably won't be changing the Width and Height of your window in runtime so if you store an X and a Y for the camera position, you can store the Width and Height of the screen and never have to look at the Viewport again except maybe to place HUD elements within the TitleSafeArea.