# Ogre3D Camera, RenderWindow and Viewport understanding

Tags: camera, coordinates, viewport, ogre, ogre3d

While looking through the tutorials I've seen the Ogre::Camera::getCameraToViewportRay method being used. I was trying understand what it does.

First I imagine a viewport, being placed somewhere in the 3D scene, let's say on the screen of the TV object. I can easily imagine how to transform the 2D coordinate on the viewport to the 3D coordinate of the scene and then to make a ray from the camera position point through that point on the VP.

But I can not understand how it's done when the VP is on the the RenderWindow(on my monitor). I mean, where is the render window in the scene, where is the point on the renderwindow's VP in the scene? How is the point on the renderwindow's VP transformed into a 3D point of the scene?

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport shows what you see through a camera, but the viewport is in front of the camera.

There is a stackoverflow post with information about the relation of camera and viewport and a nice visual illustration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7125486/2168872

The camera to viewport ray is a worldspace ray, starting from your camera and intersecting the viewport at a certain point, e.g. where your mouse cursor points to.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Do I get it right, that the my RenderWindow's viewport has some coordinates in the 3D scene? Does that mean that it's located in the scene? Is it on some fixed distance from the camera position?

Comment: Not really in the scene. It's like the photography from a camera. The range the camera "sees". You can imagine it anywhere in the scene. If you place it 10 meters before you, it's as wide as, let's say, 20 meters (depending on the camera's settings, some also show a wider range, or zoom). If you place it 100 meters before you, it's as wide as 200 meters. You could imagine it in the far end of the scene, when it is as wide as the far end you see in it. Or you could imagine having a spyglass, and while the lenses are the camera, the round "hole" (the front of the spyglass), is the viewport.

Comment: Thank you for a description!